# How can I cast a spell more quickly?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

Is there any way I can quickly cast a spell, or maybe even just recast the spell that I previously cast?

One difficulty I'm having in combat is that I'm kind of slow to click the runes for spellcasting, and I find that it slows down the overall attack speed of my party, since if I'm fiddling with the runes, I'm not swinging swords in the front ranks. First I have to right-click on the mage's empty hand to open the runes screen, then I have to click on the rune(s) I need for the spell, and then finally I have to click the button on the right to finally cast the spell. This is a lot of clicking.

[image]

Is there anything I can do to make casting or recasting of known spells more quick and automatic, or do I have to manually input the runes for the spell every single time I cast it? Are there any keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: No experience with the game, but that kind of looks like a numeric keypad layout - have you tried the numeric keypad?

Comment: @agent86 Numpad doesn't work.

Comment: One thing you can do is follow the D&D Wizard's motto: be prepared. If you know someone's gonna need a fireball to the face, set that up before you start fighting them. It'll help you get your first spell off quicker, even if it doesn't help with the second.

Comment: I find combining Tacroy's advice with the door trick is a great way to maximize my damage with respect to the enemies attacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [post](http://forums.somethingawful.com/showthread.php?threadid=3433093#post394833986) of a game's developer on Something Awful forums, it is not yet implemented, but it might be feasible for the spells to be assigned to numpad keys.

As with all such statements, it is not more than a speculation and might or might not be really coming with a future update.

Comment: Disappointing! But it sounds like it was a conscious decision on their part to make click speed a gameplay factor.

Comment: From [the FAQ on the official forums](http://www.grimrock.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=284) - Am I able to use alternative ways, like numpad instead of mouse, to cast magic?
"No, the whole UI scheme is designed in this way. There can be several spellcasting panels open at a time, so it's actually more convenient to do everything with a mouse."